# Windows 10 dual boot ubuntu start black screen problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, suspend

So I installed Windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04LTS on my desktop using unetbootin.  It works well for both os for a while.

Today, I use suspend to temporarily put my ubuntu into sleep mode. When I reboot the computer later, the computer went into a black screen in 5 secs of loading.  Restarting and F12 didn't work either. So there isn't anything I can do.

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?  Any help will be thankful.

Comment: Do you mean that not even Grub menu is shown? Or the boot hangs after you choose Ubuntu in the menu? If the latter — have you try to choose an earlier kernel version in the menu?

Comment: Nope, the Grub menu doesn't show either. Just a black screen after loading an msi graphics card screen.